# worst case of insertion sort

Tags: algorithms

what is the worst case of insertion sort ?

Comment: What did the magic google oracle say?

Comment: Wow, the magic Google oracle makes it work fast - the answer is even in the preview...

Comment: Try to google  before you ask it here...

Answer (score 1):

Wiki it:

It is O(n^2) or quadratic running time. It is more efficient in practice than selection sort and bubble sort despite the same time complexity as them.

The idea is that you need to take any element and shift elements over so that the sequence of element gradually start to look like it is in order.

You need to iterate n times in the array but do (n-1) shift per iteration.